# Why can't I redirect stdout/err of a program run by a batch file, called by another batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

If I have this batch:

### ScriptA.bat

```
someprog.exe
```

And this one:

### ScriptB.bat

```
CALL ScriptA.bat
```

And I execute a command like:

```
ScriptB.bat > test.log
```

The output from `someprog.exe` is not logged.  It flows through to the console.  How can I avoid having to explicitly pipe the output of `someprog.exe` to a file, and instead just capture that from a higher level?

(Note I ultimately want to do this with a great many scripts launching assorted exes from inside those nesting, and I can't edit them all to redirect the output of each and every sub process they invoke).

Comment: And you are positive that `FOO.exe` is not purposely writing to the `CON` device?

Comment: I tested your exact scenario but I used `IPCONFIG.exe` in `A.bat`. I executed `B.bat` accordingly: `B.bat>output.log`.  All the output from `ipconfig` was put into the log file. If you think you need STDOUT and STDERR redirected then do: `B.bat>output.log 2>&1`

Comment: Hmm... That's conceivable in this context I'm testing, but it's a third party utility.  I'm not certain how I would determine that?

Comment: Thanks for testing that!  It's not the `2>&1`, I tried that detail plenty, I just omitted it in my quick post.

Comment: Should be a no brainer to test if the program is outputting to the `CON` device only.  Just execute the program with redirection: `someprog.exe >output.log 2>&1`. If it writes to the console then you know it writes to `CON` only and not `STDOUT` or `STDERR`.

Comment: You're right!  Excellent.  That is, in fact, the problem!

Comment: How do capture that `CON` output?

Comment: You can't with a batch file.  You might be able to do it with some other 3rd party utility that can scrape the output from the console Window.  I have seen people talk about it but I have never followed up on what utility they use to do it.

Comment: Ok. Well, you've pointed me in the right direction.  Thank you!  I've been banging my head on the wall with this for way too long.  I need to capture stdout/err + con for anything which might be nested in assorted scripts I can't control.  I'll start digging for that solution now.

Comment: Try: `someprogram.exe < CON >"output.log"`

Comment: Thanks!  But it didn't work...

Comment: Here's my immediate use case exe: http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/reshacker_setup.exe  OR http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/resource_hacker.zip

Comment: Try: `ResourceHacker.exe -h` That displays the command line help on the console.  All of the functional commands dump debugging details that way too.

Comment: Here the author of "tee" discusses `con` redirection: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php apparently it's some how possible with a legacy DOS program called CTTY...

Comment: I could open a virtual COM port and capture data on that via CTTY, I suppose... But I wish there was a less work intensive solution!

Comment: Well, it seems maybe I could write a program tapping the Windows API to create my own console, and then access the internal buffers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/consoles I'm surprised to not find a utility readily available for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this on another SO thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11955380/3220983

As you'll see if reading the comments under the question, the problem I was encountering was that the messages I couldn't capture were not being piped to stdout or stderr at all!  They were going straight to the console via something akin to a `CON` redirect from inside the specific executable I was trying to use.

The link I posted shows how to launch a PowerShell script from a batch script, which captures the *entire* console window contents, inclusive of `CON` output!